# Hex of most significant nibble

Tags: c, byte, bit-manipulation, bit, nibble

I am having trouble with bitwise manipulation.

To do: The hex value of the most significant nibble of x equals y (assume 0 <= y <= 15)

Restrictions: may not use equality (==) or inequality (!=) tests, relative comparison operators, division, modulus, and multiplication, conditionals.

Problem: I need to make my function so that when msb = y it returns 1 and if it is not true 0. However, I keep getting zero even when i run it with 0xff. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great. Thank you.

```
int sig_nib(int x, int y){

int shifright = x  >> 27;
int result = shifright & y;

return (result ^ y);
}
```

Comment: The most significant nibble of int contains the sign bit, are you sure to compare it with y?

Comment: Yes, an example would be 0xABCDEF01 where y = C therefore false because it isn't the msn. While y = A would be true since it is the same as the msn. So essentially I want to compare the 4 bits of y and the 4 bits of the msn to determine if they are the same. Well that's how I believe it should be approached anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly restrictions. Who broke your compiler?

Something like this should do it:

```
bool sig_nib(int x, int y)
{
  const int top4 = (x >> 28) & 0xf;
  return !(top4 ^ y);
}
```

It uses Boolean inversion (`!`) to re-interpret the integer result from the bitwise-xor.

Comment: I had completely forgotten about the boolean type. Thank you, this makes much more sense now.